# Равномерное распределение точек на сфере

Tags: математика, алгоритм, 3d

Ищу алгоритм для "красивого" заполнения поверхности сферы однородными объектами и представляю себе входные условия на него таким образом:

1. Необходимо размещать заданное количество точек на сфере как можно более равномерно. Под *равномерно* здесь понимается примерно вот что: **для любой точки ее расстояние по сфере до ближайшей соседней как можно более велико** (назовем такое расстояние *ореолом* точки).
2. Некоторое количество точек задано сразу, **точки могут добавляться и удаляться**. При перераспределении точек они должны сдвигаться, но не прыгать, то есть **меняющие свое положение точки должны двигаться по гладким путям**. Желательно, чтобы при движении точек по путям их *ореол либо только увеличивался, либо только уменьшался* (точки либо все вместе уплотняются при добавлении новых, либо наоборот)
3. Неплохо бы продумать модификации алгоритма *для эллипсоида* или *для неоднородных объектов* (скажем, кругов различного радиуса - ореолом тогда будет наименьшее расстояние между границами)

Ясно, что здесь при позиционировании **предельная точность не так важна, как скорость поиска "красивого" распределения**. Очень желаю услышать полезные идеи по реализации таких условий, а также возможные варианты других критериев "красивого" распределения.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста пояснить третий пункт? Первые два осознать получилось, но вот с последним...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349727/generating-points-uniformly-on-a-sphere
http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/05/03/generating-uniformly-distributed-points-on-sphere/
http://www.xsi-blog.com/archives/115

Comment: Это когда уже будет годный алгоритм для точек и для сферы, можно будет думать алгоритм не только для точек, а для кругов, или не на сфере, а на сосиске (типа дирижабля :). Смысл остается тот же - объекты должны оставаться как можно дальше друг от друга

Comment: Я просмотрел вот предложенные ссылки - да, там есть очень неплохие решения как точки *разместить*, особенно понравилось с нормализацией куба. Но я ставлю вопрос, как точки *размещать*, то есть пункт 2 важен не менее, чем 1. Количество точек постоянно изменяется, и распределение должно оставаться "красивым".

Comment: Можно попытаться использовать стереографическую проекцию, после чего расставить точки на получившейся плоскости затем вместе с точками вернуться из проекции обратно на сферу. Не факт что сработает, так как только что пришла в голову идея.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection

Comment: @igumnov: равномерное распределение по _всей плоскости_ с одной стороны невозможно, с другой стороны не дало бы равномерное распределение на сфере. Нужно правильное _неравномерное_ распределение на плоскости, сможете сообразить правильную плотность (я сходу нет)?

Comment: @VladD Да скорее всего такой алгоритм не сработает, если только не понять как правильно их расставлять на проекции чтобы получить равномерное распределение на сфере. Проецировать надо конечно не всю сферу, а полушария как это делают на географических картах.

Answer (score 5):

Пусть у каждой точки есть три степени свободы: x, y и z.

На каждую точку действуют две силы:

1. Отталкивание от других точек.
2. Притяжение к поверхности сферы.

Проецируя точки на сферу, получает распределение.

При добавлении точки она будет "расталкивать" соседей.

Пример для двумерного случая:

[image: анимация расстановки точек по окружности]

Пример для трёхмерного случая:

[image: анимация перемещения точек для трёхмерного случая]

Answer (score 1):

Метод золотого сечения  (это Matlab, но думаю понятно будет)

```
num_pts = 200; % количество точек
indices = 0:num_pts + 0.5;
theta = acos(1 - 2 * indices / num_pts);
phi = pi * (1 + 5^0.5) * indices;
r = 3;
x = r .* cos(phi) .* sin(theta);
y = r .* sin(phi) .* sin(theta);
z = r .* cos(theta);
```

Источник - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere

Comment: qaru воруют контент с SO с нарушением лицензии, прогоняют его через автопереводчик, и вывешивают под видом собственного, добавляя рекламу. пожалуйста, давайте ссылки на оригинал :)